# GTK3 cairo g_signal_connect: Dont get the point

Tags: c, gtk3

i´m trying to fix it out that when i click on "button1" the "on_draw_event"-funcion is called (that works) and a line is shown in my "darea"-drawing_area (that does not work).

Here is my code:

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *button, cairo_t *darea)
{
    printf ("function: on_draw_event\n");
    cairo_set_source_rgb(darea, 0, 255, 0);
    cairo_set_line_width(darea, 0.5);

    cairo_move_to(darea, 0, 100);
    cairo_line_to(darea, 400, 100);
    cairo_stroke(darea);
    return FALSE;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *darea;
    GtkWidget *myGrid;
    GtkWidget *button1;
    GtkWidget *button2;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
    myGrid = gtk_grid_new ();
    darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();

    gtk_widget_set_size_request(darea, 400, 400);
    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("BUTTON 1");
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("QUIT");

    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(myGrid), button1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(myGrid), darea, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(myGrid), button2, 0, 2, 1, 1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), myGrid);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button2), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), darea);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

If i cange 
"g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), darea);"
to
"g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL);"
the line will be drawn, but i want that it waits for my button click. Hope someone can halp me, cant be a big problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted, your example crashes because you are connecting a drawing callback to the `clicked` signal. When called, the callback gets nonsensical arguments and dies.

To "wait for the button click", introduce a flag that tells you whether the button has been clicked. Consult that flag in `on_draw_event` and set it in the button's `clicked` callback.

Your example modified to implement the above would look like this:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *darea, cairo_t *cr,
                              gboolean *draw_line)
{
    if (!*draw_line)
        return FALSE;
    printf ("function: on_draw_event\n");
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 255, 0);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.5);

    cairo_move_to(cr, 0, 100);
    cairo_line_to(cr, 400, 100);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    return FALSE;
}

static void on_button1_clicked(GtkWidget *button, gboolean *draw_line)
{
    *draw_line = TRUE;
    /* Make sure the widget is repainted after the click.
       gtk_widget_queue_draw() should better be invoked with just the
       drawing area, but this code accesses the common parent for
       simplicity. Passing darea in a struct whose address is provided as
       user_data (along with gboolean *draw_line) is left as exercise. */
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(gtk_widget_get_parent(button));
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *darea;
    GtkWidget *myGrid;
    GtkWidget *button1;
    GtkWidget *button2;
    gboolean draw_line = FALSE;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
    myGrid = gtk_grid_new ();
    darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();

    gtk_widget_set_size_request(darea, 400, 400);
    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("BUTTON 1");
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("QUIT");

    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(myGrid), button1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(myGrid), darea, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(myGrid), button2, 0, 2, 1, 1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), myGrid);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button2), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button1_clicked), &draw_line);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), &draw_line);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, works perfect and now i know how to handle this. i would like to show you my new code but i dont know how. just can write this comment. just a small misstake, just "return" does not work. i changed to "return FALSE".

Comment: @Arcanix To show the code, you can upload it to [a pastebin site](http://pastebin.com) and post the short url in the comment. I've amended the answer to return `FALSE`, thanks for the correction.

Comment: thank you for this hint. you can find my new code here: http://pastebin.com/c9F5pw0s i know its not the best code, but it works.i did not work with struct yet, but i will use it more in my next projects.

Comment: @Arcanix Address of `user_data` should be passed from `main` as the "user data" parameter to `g_signal_connect`, not kept as a global variable. The global variable will work in this simple example, but it will hinder reusability if you wish, for example, to instantiate two such widgets...

Comment: again thank you very much! now i think i fixed it like you told: http://pastebin.com/X0e4shwc . problem is now that i have 2 funktions for moving the line up und down (on_button_clicked_down) and (on_button_clicked_up). any hint for me how to fix this in only one function?

Comment: @Arcanix You got it. :) Your callbacks are now usable from multiple places (provided each declares its own `main_struct`).

Comment: Having two functions for moving up/down is fine in itself, since they do different things. If you're worried about code duplication, you can reduce it with a helper function, e.g. `void draw_line(GtkWidget *window, struct main_struct *ctx, int offset) { ctx->draw_line = TRUE; ctx->y_pos += offset; gtk_widget_queue_draw(ctx->darea); }`. The actual callbacks now only contain calls to `draw_line(-10)` and `draw_line(+10)` respectively. Helper functions like that are the typical strategy for reducing code duplication in C.